# How to get all YouTube comments with Python's gdata module?

Tags: python, youtube-api, gdata

Looking to grab all the comments from a given video, rather than go one page at a time.

```
from gdata import youtube as yt
from gdata.youtube import service as yts

client = yts.YouTubeService()
client.ClientLogin(username, pwd) #the pwd might need to be application specific fyi

comments = client.GetYouTubeVideoComments(video_id='the_id')
a_comment = comments.entry[0]
```

The above code with let you grab a single comment, likely the most recent comment, but I'm looking for a way to grab *all* the comments at once. Is this possible with Python's `gdata` module?

---

The Youtube API docs for [comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments), the comment feed [docs](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.youtube.html#YouTubeVideoCommentFeed) and the Python API [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python#Comments)

Comment: This was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941803/using-youtube-api-to-get-all-comments-from-a-video-with-the-json-feed) with a solution utilizing PHP, since the YouTube PHP API has a call that allows it. I don't think a pure Python answer is out there.

Comment: @KenB I saw that too. That's a shame. The video in question has 9k comments and I don't think making 360 `GetNextLink` calls is the best way.

Comment: The URL `www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=video_id` has a parseable comment list, but it's a long load time. Suppose I could try that.

Comment: Regardless of what method you use, if you're returning 9k comments all at once, you will have a long load time. I think this is why the API doesn't offer it; you usually wouldn't want to do it all at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following achieves what you asked for using the [Python YouTube API](https://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.youtube.html):

```
from gdata.youtube import service

USERNAME = 'username@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'a_very_long_password'
VIDEO_ID = 'wf_IIbT8HGk'

def comments_generator(client, video_id):
    comment_feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(video_id=video_id)
    while comment_feed is not None:
        for comment in comment_feed.entry:
             yield comment
        next_link = comment_feed.GetNextLink()
        if next_link is None:
             comment_feed = None
        else:
             comment_feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(next_link.href)

client = service.YouTubeService()
client.ClientLogin(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

for comment in comments_generator(client, VIDEO_ID):
    author_name = comment.author[0].name.text
    text = comment.content.text
    print("{}: {}".format(author_name, text))
```

Unfortunately the API limits the number of entries that can be retrieved to **1000**. This was the error I got when I tried a tweaked version with a hand crafted `GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed` URL parameter:

```
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 400, 'body': 'You cannot request beyond item 1000.', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}
```

Note that the same principle should apply to retrieve entries in other feeds of the API.

If you want to hand craft the `GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed` URL parameter, its format is:

```
'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{video_id}/comments?start-index={sta‌​rt_index}&max-results={max_results}'
```

The following restrictions apply: `start-index <= 1000` and `max-results <= 50`.

Comment: Great. Do you know if there's a way to manually set the `start_index` or `items_per_page`? Setting it on the first set of comments doesn't seem to doing anything.

Comment: You just need to pass an URL with the following format to `GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed`: `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{video_id}/comments?start-index={start_index}&max-results={max_results}`. The following restrictions apply: `start-index <= 1000` and `max-results <= 50`.

Comment: Note that to pass the URI you need to pass `uri` as a kwarg: `yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(uri='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/...')`

Comment: @Roshambo: `uri` is the first positional argument, so specifying it as a kwarg is redundant and not required. What makes you say that it must be a kwarg?

Comment: @PedroRomano ah, didn't realize it was the first argument. The PyDocs are so dense I must’ve missed that.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've got for now, but it's not using the API and gets slow when there's several thousand comments.

```
import bs4, re, urllib2
#grab the page source for vide
data = urllib2.urlopen(r'http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=video_id') #example XhFtHW4YB7M
#pull out comments
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
cmnts = soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'comment yt-tile-default'})
#do something with them, ie count them
print len(cmnts)
```

Note that due to 'class' being a builtin python name, you can't do regular searches for 'startwith' via regex or lambdas as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2830550/541208), since you're using a dict, over regular parameters. It also gets pretty slow due to BeautifulSoup, but it needs to get used because `etree` and `minidom` don't find matching tags for some reason. Even after `prettyfying()` with `bs4`

Comment: Hi, interest answer but I think that the html structure has changed. Do you use an alternative tag instead of `comment yt-tile-default`? Thank you!

Comment: @Thoth I haven't made use of this in a while, but open up the dev tools and edit my answer if you find out