# Google Sites API failed to return entries which are not in first chunk

Tags: google-sites, google-data-api

I am trying list out all available lists, webpages, announcements, file cabinets present in Google site, by using Query(with .Net Google Data APIs):

"https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/site/mysite1?kind=filecabinet,listpage,webpage,announcementspage".

If there are approx. <500 items present in Google Site, then it works properly. Able to list out all available page.

But, Google Sites with approx. >500 items (including all attachments, comments, pages etc.) this query returns only those items which are present in first chunk. Next Chunk URL is empty in this case, so I am not able to query next chunk by using Start Index property and failed to list all available pages here.

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the same problem, I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826680/how-to-get-all-youtube-comments-with-pythons-gdata-module/rG9Or_xm_Bc) about the Python YouTube API.

Content feed queries return a single chunk of results. You can use the GetNextLink method to retrieve the next chunk, if any. This is described in the Data API [protocol reference](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#Queries) under "query results."

Here's a Python solution (with 2 Legged OAuth for Google Apps) that relies on the answer to the YouTube API question mentioned earlier.

```
CONSUMER_KEY = 'some_key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'some_secret'
REQUESTOR_ID = 'some_id@' + CONSUMER_KEY
DOMAIN = 'some_domain'

def content_generator(client):
    content_feed = client.GetContentFeed()
    while content_feed is not None:
        for content in content_feed.entry:
             yield content
        next_link = content_feed.GetNextLink()
        if next_link is None:
             content_feed = None
        else:
             content_feed = client.GetContentFeed(next_link.href)

client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(source='some_source', site=SITE, domain=DOMAIN)
client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.TwoLeggedOAuthHmacToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, REQUESTOR_ID)

for page in content_generator(client):
    # do something
    print(page.page_name)
```