# Retrieve comments from youtube leads to non deterministic behaviour

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

Currently I'm trying to retrieve all comments of a youtube video with python. I'm using following code to get the comments

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from gdata.youtube import service
import xmltodict

def comments_generator(client, video_id):
    baseUrl="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%s/comments?orderby=published&max-results=50" %video_id
    comment_feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(baseUrl)
    while comment_feed is not None:
        for comment in comment_feed.entry:
            yield comment
        next_link = comment_feed.GetNextLink()
        if next_link is None:
            comment_feed = None
        else:
            try:
                comment_feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(next_link.href)
            except:
                print "Something went wrong. Couldn't follow next link"
                comment_feed = None

client = service.YouTubeService()
commentNumber=0
for comment in comments_generator(client, "Ci0HsPELE2o"):
        commentNumber+=1
        dictVersion=xmltodict.parse(str(comment))
        replyCount = str(dictVersion["ns0:entry"]["ns1:replyCount"])
        author_name = comment.author[0].name.text
        date = comment.published
        text = comment.content.text
        publishTime = date.text.split("T")[0]
        print "Comment #%s %s" %(commentNumber,date.text)
        print("{}: {}".format(author_name, text))
        print "Reply-Count: %s" %replyCount
        print "\n"
```

Which is an improved/adjusted version of the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826680/how-to-get-all-youtube-comments-with-pythons-gdata-module).

In principle it's working but there is some non **deterministic behaviour**.
When I try to retrieve all comments of some Youtube vids I get a different number of comments from time to time although the number of comments didn't change when I open the video in the browser.

Then I investigated further and found that some comments in the middle of the chronological ordered list are sometimes missing and sometimes not, seemingly the same few comments over all tries, but in varying number. That holds true for some specific youtube videos but apparently not for all.
The comment count varies up to 100 of overall 4000 comments for some videos.

One example of such a non deterministic behaviour is the vid with ID: **Ci0HsPELE2o**

Expected behaviour is, that I get 30 real comments(without replies) and sometimes I get every single comment, but when I try excactly the same program 1 hour later or so, one comment is missing, most of the time this one:

```
Comment #19 2011-09-03T10:44:07.000Z
Author: Stephane Keeper
```

I tried literally everything but didn't find any systematic in this problem and therefore couldn't fix it.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Added working example which reproduces the problem

Comment: Please include a short, complete program that others can run. Please describe the output you see when you run the program, and the output you expected to see. See [these instructions on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and particulary, [how to write a good example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I added a working example which reproduces my problem(at least sometimes, as it seems to be non deterministic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python web crawler sometimes returns half of the source code, sometimes all of it... From the same website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820059/python-web-crawler-sometimes-returns-half-of-the-source-code-sometimes-all-of-i)