# Embedding Youtube comments inside a web page

Tags: html, xhtml, youtube, youtube-api

I want to embed youtube comments inside a webpage. I found this code:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    ...
    <media:group>
      ...
    </media:group>
    <gd:comments>
      <gd:feedLink href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/4eYSpIz2FjU/comments'/>
    </gd:comments>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I tried to include this code inside a page to test but it doesn't display the comments. But when I visited the url http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/4eYSpIz2FjU/comments
 comments displayed sucessfully.

Am I embedding it wrong? Should I include any other script references to access Youtube comments?

Comment: I don't know much from Youtube's API, but I found [another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941803/using-youtube-api-to-get-all-comments-from-a-video-with-the-json-feed)

Comment: @SergioMarconni thanks for your reply.......i will go through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a working solution, someone posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194619/getting-youtube-video-information-using-javascript-jquery) code a few years ago, I don't take credit for it.

I tested it out on my website, and it works pretty well.

You are obviously going to want to add styling and remove some of the inline html styling. On a side note, you are going to need to add the video id. If you don't know how to do this, either replace the PHP calls (`<?php echo $_GET['v']; ?>`) with the id, or simply define v somewhere in PHP. Note: if you are going to manually add in the id's there are 2 locations where you are going to have to do this.. hope it helps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
    function getYouTubeInfo() {
            $.ajax({
                    url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<?php echo $_GET['v']; ?>?v=2&alt=json",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data) { parseresults(data); }
            });
    }

    function parseresults(data) {
            var title = data.entry.title.$t;
            var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
            var viewcount = data.entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
            var author = data.entry.author[0].name.$t;
            $('#title').html(title);
            $('#description').html('<b>Description</b>: ' + description);
            $('#extrainfo').html('<b>Author</b>: ' + author + '<br/><b>Views</b>: ' + viewcount);
            getComments(data.entry.gd$comments.gd$feedLink.href + '&max-results=50&alt=json', 1);
    }

    function getComments(commentsURL, startIndex) {
            $.ajax({
                    url: commentsURL + '&start-index=' + startIndex,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(key, val) {
                            $('#comments').append('<br/>Author: ' + val.author[0].name.$t + ', Comment: ' + val.content.$t);
                    });
                    if ($(data.feed.entry).size() == 50) { getComments(commentsURL, startIndex + 50); }
                    }
            });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
            getYouTubeInfo();
    });
    </script>
    <title>YouTube</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="grey">
    <div align="center">
            <br/><br/>
            <div id="title" style="color: #dddddd">Could not find a title</div><br/>
            <iframe title="Youtube Video Player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['v']; ?>?fs=1&autoplay=1&loop=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
            <br/><br/>
            <div id="description" style="width:400px; background-color: #dddddd; font-size:10px; text-align:left;">Could not find a description</div>
            <div id="extrainfo" style="width:400px; background-color: #dddddd; font-size:10px; text-align:left;">Could not find extra information</div>
            <div id="comments" style="width:400px; background-color: #dddddd; font-size:10px; text-align:left;">Could not find comments</div>
    </div>
```